# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Map<string, string[]>' has no index signature

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, hashmap

I am declaring a Map as follows:

```
 exampleMap:Map<string, string[]>;
 exampleMap['A']=['X,'XX'],
```

I am getting the following errror and dont know what it means nor how to fix it.

**error TS7052: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Map<string, string[]>' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'exampleMap.get'?**

Any tips/suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the code that produces that error? The code in your question is incomplete and will not result in such an error.

Comment: I wrote some code that just passed without an error, from es3 until esnext in each versions.
let exampleMap1: Map<string, string[]>;
exampleMap1 = new Map();
exampleMap1.set('A', ['X', 'XX']);

const exampleMap2 = new Map<string, string[]>();
exampleMap2.clear();
exampleMap2.set('B', ['Y', 'YY']);

function a(exampleMap: Map<string, string[]>) {
  exampleMap.clear();
}

Comment: @JanosVinceller: thank you so much!! My mistake was I was setting the value as exampleMap['A']=['X,'XX'], instead of using exampleMap.set('A',['X,'XX']). Thank you!!

Comment: But then Mary, you forgot that part of your code, which would have been pretty important to the solution. Please edit your question.